# Staging and production environment on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, production-environment, staging

I want to create staging environment on heroku of an existing app. I want to know two things

1) Is it using same database of production or not? If yes then either it requires some settings or not?

2) Is the url's of both staging and production environments change or not?

Please don't give links

Comment: You should set up your staging site with a different database and a different url.  The whole idea of staging is that anything can break at any moment, or you could do any action while testing, and this won't affect your users.  If you used the same database then some bug or test could wipe all your real data out.

Comment: But I want to use same database . Is it possible?

Comment: Like walking into traffic with your eyes closed, it's certainly possible but a really terrible idea.  Unless of course you mean that the choice of DBMS (Postgres, Mysql, SQLite), and the data **schema** is the same, but the actual data is different, in which case that is exactly what you **should** do.

Comment: Issue is that I want to use existing database for both cases. I cannot want to refill new database because I contain a lot of database. That's why I want to use for staging also

Comment: You can **copy** the data from your production database to your staging database, but they need to be different databases.

Answer (score 1):

1. No. Two different databases.
2. Yes it will be different.

staging and production are normally on two different hosts, with two different databases, two different url's.

Comment: But I want to use same database . Is it possible?

Comment: **Why** do you want to use the same database, in the face of people more knowledgeable than you telling you not to?

Comment: Possible yes, but you do not want to do that at all! The best option would be to make a script that would copy the production database and importing to your staging database, but in general you don't want to be able to touch the production database everywhere else than in production.

Comment: Issue is that I want to use existing database for both cases. I cannot want to refill new database because I contain a lot of database. That's why I want to use for staging also

Comment: Technically speaking, if you wanted to create a "second production environment" that you'd call staging, you could yes. You'll need a very good reason to do so though (a data migration for instance).

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a separate database. I cloned the one from production to get a good simulation.
2. Not sure if I understand what you mean. But if the question is whether staging and production have the same URL then no. Staging usually looks like "prod-url"-staging